# Lottie Splash Screen with Expo - animated splash screen with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen, lottie

I am looking for a way to create an animated Splash Screen in React Native project using Expo.

I found Lottie as a solution, but the only info I can get about it is about the animations within the app itself - is there ANY possible solution that would allow a creation of an animated splash screen with Expo? For now, I have only a static png file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example provided in the Expo docs here:

https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-splash-screen

Although it's technically not an animated splash screen, but a way to automatically hide the static splash screen (which would be the first frame of your animation) and then immediately switch to playing the animation once the app is loaded. I'm doing it this way and it works well enough.

This NPM module seems to work in a similar fashion so maybe you could use that

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-splash-screen

But it's still not a native animated splash screen which I don't think is possible using even vanilla React Native let alone Expo.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using this module for custom animated splash screen using expo react native project. I hope it will work for you too.

Here is the module link: [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-splash-screen)

Let me know if you need any other help.